# Complex sliver in CustomScrollView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I have List of FeaturedBlock. Featured block contains header and list of products. So the problem is that I'm not sure how to add that block(header with gridList) to CustomScrollView. So the structure is:

```
--------------
|SliverAppBar|
--------------
...some elements
--------------
|   Header   |   ----> Featured Block header
--------------
------ -------
|    | |     |   ----> Featured Block products
|    | |     |
------ -------
------ -------
|    | |     |
|    | |     |
------ -------
--------------
|   Header   |  ----> Featured Block header
--------------
------ -------
|    | |     |   ----> Featured Block products
|    | |     |
------ -------
------ -------
|    | |     |
|    | |     |
------ -------
```

So, how to convert FeaturedBlock to Sliver element?

Comment: "So, how to convert FeaturedBlock to Sliver element?".. Have you tried using the `SliverGrid` Widget ?

Comment: Is it possible to have slivergrid with crossAxisAlignment = 1 for header and crossAxisAlignment = 2 for product?

Comment: use `SliverList` which builds two types of views: a header and "normal item" (a `Row` for example) that has two `Flexible` / `Expanded` child widgets with the same `flex` value

Comment: "a Row that has a `Flexible/Expanded` child widgets", won't that become cumbersome when there are lot of featured block products @pskink ? Also, the featured block products, I assume, will be dynamic.

Comment: How could you write it? CustomScrollView -> SliverList -> elementSize/2  * row?

Comment: yep `CustomScrollView -> SliverList`, that list depending on your data model would build 2 different types of widgets

Comment: It'll work with static items size)) For example, how could you know when to create row widget and when widgets inside of row? I

Comment: So what is the problem: how do you know how many rows you need to create? Size of list of featuredBlock is dynamically change, at the same time size of list of products from featuredBlock is changing too.

Comment: what is your input data model? where do you have a list of your products? where are the headers taken from? are they just random boxes (like adverts) or they are related to items below?

Comment: class FeaturedBox{String header; List<Product> products; }

Comment: @void what you mean by "cumbersome"? i am assuming that he has couple of dozens featured block headers max and not 1000s of them since nobody would want to scroll that amount of data otherwise

Comment: Yeah, it was really difficult to understand, but you were right)) please, post your answer for the next searchers, I'll upwote it))

Comment: Unfortunately, feature.products.chunkedWithPadding(2) gives me an error,  "chunkedWithPadding(2)" not found! Where did you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `SliverPersistentHeader` and `SliverGrid.count` and change `crossAxisCount` per your request 
working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Collapsing List Demo')),
        body: CollapsingList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate({
    @required this.minHeight,
    @required this.maxHeight,
    @required this.child,
  });
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;
  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => math.max(maxHeight, minHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}

class CollapsingList extends StatelessWidget {
  SliverPersistentHeader makeHeader(String headerText) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: 60.0,
        maxHeight: 200.0,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue, child: Center(child: Text(headerText))),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          expandedHeight: 200.0,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
        makeHeader('Header Section 1'),
        SliverGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
          ],
        ),
        makeHeader('Header Section 2'),
        SliverGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
          ],
        ),
        makeHeader('Header Section 3'),
        SliverGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
          ],
        ),
        makeHeader('Header Section 4'),
        SliverGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
            Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

working demo 2

[image]

full code 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

List<Widget> widgetList = [];

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int count = 0;

  SliverPersistentHeader makeHeader(String headerText) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: 60.0,
        maxHeight: 200.0,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue, child: Center(child: Text(headerText))),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _add() {
    count = count + 1;
    widgetList.add(makeHeader(count.toString()));
    widgetList.add(
      SliverGrid.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
          Container(color: Colors.orange, height: 150.0),
        ],
      ),
    );

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Collapsing List Demo')),
        body: CollapsingList(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _add,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate({
    @required this.minHeight,
    @required this.maxHeight,
    @required this.child,
  });
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;
  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => math.max(maxHeight, minHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}

class CollapsingList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          expandedHeight: 200.0,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
        ...widgetList
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!)) You'r adding blocks statically, how to add them dinamically?

Comment: see full code 2 and working demo 2. use List<Widget>

Comment: Finally!)) Thanks, I wasted 2 days in this! I think in future Google should add an opportunity to change weight of children elements of SliverGrid!